# .Net Client App Azure AD Authentication Cookie Authentication And then Bearer token to call downstream API

Tags: c#, vb.net, azure, authentication, bearer-token

I am using Azure AD Authentication for Web Forms Applications as well as ASP.NET MVC (client applications) Framework 4.8.

I use Owin Startup class to configure cookie authentication into Azure AD.

app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthOpts)

Now I need to call downstream API (rest and SOAP) using httpclient and soap client and want to understand the best way forward as adding existing authentication cookie to header in httpclient/soap client doesn't seem to be an option. Any examples would be great.

User is already logged using azure ad OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions so getting the user to log in again before calling a downstream api doesnt seem to an option.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to use `.AddDownstreamWebApi()` of `Microsoft.Identity.Web` from your startup class, which requests tokens and calls the downstream web API.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public class Startup
{
  // ...
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
  // ...
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
               .AddDownstreamWebApi("MyApi", Configuration.GetSection("GraphBeta"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Configure a web API that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#option-2-call-a-downstream-web-api-other-than-microsoft-graph)

Comment: My application asp.net and not core so i am using the Owin Startup class.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant ="",
                TokenValidationParameters = 
                }
            });

      
}
it does not have the  Public Sub ConfigureServices(services As IServiceCollection) method.